# Systemd service to set default printer

Tags: printer, systemd

At startup, the default printer shall be set globally with `lpoptions -d ...` run by root. I have created a systemd service to do this. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not (`/etc/cups/lpoptions` file is not created). If I restart the service manually with `systemctl restart ...`, it always works. So I suspect that the service is called too early during the startup procedure sometimes. This is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
Requires=printer.target
After=printer.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/setdefaultprinter.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I have chosen the `Require` and `After` statements in an effort to make the service run as late as possible. But it does not seem to be enough. How can I make the service run *last*?

**Workaround:** I ended up adding the default printer manually with that service. The syntax of `/etc/cups/lpoptions` is easy, just put

```
Default XXX
```

where XXX is replaced by the name of the printer.

Comment: Have you checked what specifically it complains about when it's unable to create the options file?

Comment: Yes. It does not complain at all. The service is reported as successfully started by `systemctl`. The output of the `lpoptions` command is normal, and the return code is 0. I suspect it makes its changes alright, but they are overwritten in a later stage of the process.

Comment: I added a loop after `lpoptions` command that checks every second for 10 seconds if `/etc/cups/lpoptions` is there. All 10 tests say it is not there. So it's probably not created at all, contrary to my previous hypothesis.